# Modifying LSTM to include forecast

Tags: long-short-term-memory

I am looking at LSTM example [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/?unapproved=485429&moderation-hash=4df84fbc7e6d58bc190deee3b48ef6dd#comment-485429)

However, I am not sure how to modify the setup if I have forecast available (assuming perfect forecast) for TEMP: Temperature and PRES: Pressure at time t.

i.e. `pollution_t = fn(TEMP_t, PRES_t, TEMP_t_1, PRES_t_1, ..., othervariables and lagged values)`

_t represents the perfect forecast available

_t_1 represents the variable values at previous time steps

Basically I am looking for something of the following setup:

[image]